# Format and Error in my code for a Custom TableView + Segment Controller

Tags: swift, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

So I created a View Controller that has two TableViews and a Segment Control. The code below give me two errors.

1. (return serviceImage.count) gives me an error saying the code after return will never be executed.

2.(cell.myReviewPic!.image = UIImage(named: reviewPhoto[indexPath.row])) returns an error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

My code

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    myTableServiceU.reloadData()
    myTableService.reloadData()
}


@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableServiceU: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableService: UITableView!

let serviceName: [String] = ["Whataburger", "Red Lobster", "Pizzahut", "McDonalds", "Burger King", "Sushi Garden", "In & Out Burger", "Canes", "Jimmy Johns"]

let serviceImage: [String] = ["place1,", "place2", "plac3", "place4", "place5", "place6", "place7", "place8", "place9"]

let serviceNumber: [String] = ["38", "35", "29", "25", "23", "19", "17", "12", "11"]

let brandPhoto: [String] = ["TK", "MC", "BA"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableService.dataSource = self
    myTableService.delegate = self

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        return  brandPhoto.count
    case 1:
        return  serviceName.count
        return  serviceImage.count
        return  serviceNumber.count
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ServiceCell


    switch(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        cell.myReviewPic.image = UIImage(named: brandPhoto[indexPath.row])
        break

    case 1:
        cell.myServiceName.text = serviceName[indexPath.row]
        cell.myServiceImage.image = UIImage(named: serviceImage[indexPath.row])
        cell.myServiceNumber.text = serviceNumber[indexPath.row]
        break

    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with 3 returns ?

Answer (score 0):

```
return  serviceName.count
return  serviceImage.count // Line will be ignored
return  serviceNumber.count // Line will be ignored
```

> [...] code after return will never be executed.

It's just a warning since only `serviceName` array will return it's count.

```
cell.myReviewPic!.image = UIImage(named: reviewPhoto[indexPath.row]))
```

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

`myReviewPic` is nil and you are trying to force-unwrap it using `!`. Might not be connected to your ServiceCell nib/xib via an IBOutlet.